# What is the average number of objects that are not in their place in permutations of n objects?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> In the permutations of n objects, how many objects in every
>   permutation are not in their place on average?

For example in the permutation (2314), the objects 1,2 and 3 are not in their place. Therefore, three objects are not in their place.

I tried to solve this by calculating the number of permutations with 1, 2, 3, ... objects not in their place one by one but it ends up wrong. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Linearity of expectation?

Comment: Maybe it can help to look at https://oeis.org/A008290

Comment: The result in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985845/if-s-1-2-dots-n-and-p-nk-be-the-number-of-permutations-of-s-having) is what you need; one of the answers incorporates **Angina Seng**’s suggestion.

Comment: Burnside's Lemma is probably overkill, but it does solve the problem instantly.