# Bijective proof involving fixed points and symmetric group on $n$ letters?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, group-isomorphism

There is the following question here:
[If $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $P_n(k)$ be the number of permutations of $S$ having $k$ fixed points, then $\sum_{k=0}^nk.P_{n}(k)=n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985845/if-s-1-2-dots-n-and-p-nk-be-the-number-of-permutations-of-s-having):

> Let $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then $i \in S$ is said to be a fixed point of a permutation $p$ or $S$ if $p(i) = i$. Let $P_n(k) $ be the number of permutations of $S$ which have $k$ fixed point.
>
> Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^nk\cdot P_{n}(k) = n!$.

There were some beautiful probabilistic proofs given. However, I'm wondering if there is a proof by coming up with an explicit bijection from the left-hand side to the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

$\sum_{k=0}^nk\cdot P_n(k)$ enumerates ordered pairs $(\pi,x)$, such that $\pi:[n]\to [n]$ is a bijection, $x\in [n]$, and $\pi(x)=x$.

For any fixed $x$, there is a bijection between permutations $\pi$ for which $\pi(x)=x$, and permutations $\pi$ for which $\pi(n)=n$. Simply consider the permutation $\pi$ becomes when you rename $n$ to $x$, and $x$ to $n$.

Therefore, $\sum_{k=0}^n kP_n(k)$ enumerates ordered pairs $(\pi,x)$ where $\pi:[n]\to [n]$ is a permutation, $\pi(n)=n$ and $x\in [n]$.

It is obvious now that the number of such ordered pairs is $(n-1)!\cdot n$; there are $(n-1)!$ choices for a permutation which fixes $n$, and $n$ choices for $x$. Furthermore, it is easy to use a permutation $\pi$ of $[n-1]$, together with an $n$-way choice of $x$, to make bijectively permutation of $[n]$; simply insert the number $n$ at position $x$ in $\pi$. This completes the bijection from ordered pairs $(\pi,x)$ for which $\pi(x)=x$ to all permutations of $[n]$.

---

Here is an illustration of the bijection. We can think of $\sum_{k=0}^n kP_k(n)$ as counting permutations $\pi$ where one of the fixed points of $\pi$ is circled. We want a bijection between these "annotated permutations" and regular permutations. The bijection is this; with the annotated permutation written in one-line notation,

- Delete the circled element, $x$.
- Decrease all remaining numbers greater than $x$ by one, so all numbers are between $1$ and $n-1$,
- Insert $n$ at spot $x$ in the permutation.

Here is an example, where $n=5$:

$$
[3,\;\boxed{2},\;5,\;4,\;1]\to [3,\;5,\;4,\;1]\to [2,\;4,\;3,\;1]\to [2,\;\color{red}5,\;4,\;3,\;,1]
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that this bijection is easier (it is actually the most elementary way of proving that the average number of fixed points is 1 regardless of $n$):

For any pair $(i,p)$ of a fixed point $i$ in a permutation $p$, let $p'$ the resulting permutation when you move $i$ to the last place. Conversely, for any permutation $p$, modify it by moving the last term $i$ to the $i$-th place, and if $p'$ is the resulting permutation consider the pair $(i,p')$.

It is clear that they are inverse maps.

Comment: I am confused at the current state of this answer. It has no downvotes and no comments, but (at this moment) two votes to delete and two moderator flags indicating that it's incorrect. Mods don't check for correctness. I don't understand this answer and am about to downvote it. But I find it very odd to vote to delete without either downvoting or commenting.

Comment: It's correct! Maybe I should explain a little more? Take for instance $(4,p)$, the number $4$ fixed in the permutation $p=28147653$; it is mapped onto $p'=28176534$. As an example of the inverse map, the initial permutation $p$ would be mapped to $(3,q)$, where $q=28314765$.